# MYSQL in C# how to add to my using

Tags: c#, mysql

I did every thing like copying the data.mysql.dll in many folders but still i am not able to use `Using System.data.MySqlClient`, in C#, please help me.

Comment: also I installed MySql dotNet connector but not able to use System.Data.MySqlClient

Comment: You need to add a reference. Google that.

Comment: thank you this part is solved. Also I was looking for System.Data.MySqlClient but these 2 was correct : using MySql.Data.Types;
using MySql.Data.MySqlClient;

Answer (score 0):

I installed those three packages on .NetCore to be able to connect to MySQL Database and use EntityFramework.

```
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore -Version 2.0.3
Install-Package Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Tools -Version 2.0.3
Install-Package Pomelo.EntityFrameworkCore.MySql -Version 2.0.1
```

Pomelo is a thirdparty package to can use Entity framework with MySQL.

I hope this help you.